# Get all text in Pararagraph tag

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I have html code like :

```
<div class="main">
    <p>The match is going well,
    <a> john </a> 
    is playing awesome </p>
</div>
```

I have an xpath function as  `//div[@class="main"]/p/text()`

it only returns `The match is going well, is playing awesome`

but i want the result to be

> The match is going well, john is playing awesome

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space). This will also handle the line breaks, which are significant in this case and will not be removed by the parser.

```
normalize-space(//div[@class="main"]/p)
```

---

**Edit based on great comment:**

All of the nodes in your input could be broken down into the following XPaths:

```
/div
/div/@class
/div/p
/div/p/text()[1]
/div/p/a
/div/p/a/text()
/div/p/text()[2]
```

As you can see, there are 2 text nodes that are direct children of `p` (`The match is going well,` and `is playing awesome`). The other text node (`john`), is a child of `a`.

This is the reason your original xpath (`//div[@class="main"]/p/text()`) was returning the results you saw.

Comment: You should perhaps also explain why the text content of the `a` element is not included in `//div[@class="main"]/p/text()`. As far as I can see, that's what the OP does not understand well.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - Very good point. I updated my answer with what I hope is an ok explanation. Please feel free to add/clarify anything I might have missed. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Daniel I got what the problem is that you have specified but i need help with  how to i get the full string `The match is going well, john is playing awesome` as a end result ?

Comment: I think i solved my problem with `xpath ('//div[@class="main"]/p/text() | //div[@class="main"]/p/*/text()')` which allow  me to select all the text from `p` tag as well as all the child elements of it,

Comment: @VikramSangat Does my answer not work for you? It works with every processor I've tried.